# Does firefox4 not support canvas yet?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I tried the following code but firefox4 does not display me anything..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.strokeStyle = '#990000';
context.strokeRect(20,30,100,50);
alert(context);
</script>

 <canvas id="canvas1" width="200px" height="200px">Your browser does not   support canvas </canvas>
```

This code is inside body tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to understand the order in which the file is executed by the browser.
Here is the way in which the browser is reading this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.strokeStyle = '#990000';
context.strokeRect(20,30,100,50);
alert(context);
</script>

 <canvas id="canvas1" width="200px" height="200px">Your browser does not   support canvas </canvas>
```

1. Body tag begins
2. Script tag begins
3. Find element with ID `canvas1`
4. Canvas1 Does not exist, save canvas as null(i take as nothing)
5. Context = `nothing.getContext('2d');`
6. `alert(nothing)`
7. End Script
8. Begin Canvas, since supported dont show what is inside
9. end body tag

---

*So to make it visible you just have to edit your code like this:-*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Sample by RHNVRM(aka rohan verma)</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--Canvas-->
 <canvas id="canvas1" width="200px" height="200px">Your browser does not   support canvas </canvas>
<!--Begin Script-->
<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.strokeStyle = '#990000';
context.strokeRect(20,30,100,50);
alert(context);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**NOTE:** *When using Javascript there is no need to mention it in HTML5.*

Answer (score 0):

According to this search http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=firefox4+canvas firefox 4 supports canvas.

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<canvas id="canvas1" width="200px" height="200px">Your browser does not   support canvas </canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.strokeStyle = '#990000';
context.strokeRect(20,30,100,50);
alert(context);
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```